# Array as index for Zend_Search_Lucene_Field

Tags: php, lucene, zend-lucene

This is what works:

```
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('Image', $item['Image']['localName']));
```

which indexes the field, and it's accessible later in my view helper as this:

```
$item['Image']
```

However, what I want (without a work-around in my view helper,) is for it to be accessible like this:

```
$item['Image']['localName']
```

... This doesn't work:

```
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text(array('Image' => 'localName'), $item['Image']['localName']));
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text` expects the first parameter to be a `string`, not an `array`. Therefore, the proposed method is not possible.